# disk IO vs MySQL query in PHP

Tags: mysql, performance, io, disk

I'm writing a remote API in PHP that needs to perform a comparison against a supplied parameter in every call. The supplied parameter will need to be checked against 1 to 50 dynamic values (around 15 bytes in length each) or so, depending on the internal state of the API.

My question is, for the purpose of making the calls as fast as possible, would it make more sense to simply load the comparison values from a flat file (perhaps even as an .inc to be parsed immediately)in each call, or load the comparison values from a MySQL table in each call. The cost of writing changes to these values is not important since that won't happen very often.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only have 50 items, just include them in your php code.  you're already reading that file from disk anyway... and php has it's own bytecode caching.  using mysql will necessitate that you open a socket and make a network request every time.

Comment: This was my first intuition, and now seems like an even better choice now that you've made me aware of PHP's intrinsic bytecode caching.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a maximum of 50 values, I'd load them from the database once, and cache them in memory.

Comment: how would you maintain a cache across requests?

Comment: i assume he is talking about the mysql query cache.

Comment: Not talking about the mysql query cache. I don't know PHP. If not possible, then cache with a local memcached or redis instance.

Comment: I think using something like APC might be ideal in this situation, but due to the relatively small amount of data I'm loading, I'm not sure that introducing a new dependency may be worth the performance gains. I may have to do some testing.